# Ayuda con SubCosultas en ORACLE

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, subconsultas

Hola necesito ayuda en este ejercicio, no puedo hacer que el monto del el empleado se sume y de 300.000.
Aca estan las imagenes con las tablas y el resultado que tiene que aparecer:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTexV.jpg

```
SELECT pnombre AS "NOMBRE", appaterno AS "APELLIDO", SUM(monto_total) AS 
"MONTO TOTAL VENTAS"
FROM empleado JOIN ventas
USING(id_empleado)
GROUP BY id_empleado, pnombre, appaterno, monto_total
HAVING id_empleado = ANY(SELECT COUNT(id_empleado)
                          FROM empleado
                          WHERE id_empleado = 1);
```

Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido, por favor dale en editar y añade en formato de texto tanto las tablas como el resultado que buscas, una vez hecho eso selecciona y presiona `ctrl + k`

Comment: Proque estas igualando el id de empleado a la cuenta de los empleados con id_empleado = 1? eso no tiene ningun sentido

Comment: ¿Que debo hacer entonces?

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema para empezar esta en que quieres meter dentro de id_empleado a otro resultado, por regla general en base de datos nunca debes de modificar el id, solo se debe de consultar. Ahora para tu problema a solución es relativamente sencilla, lo único que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT SUM(monto_total)
  FROM empleado JOIN ventas
```

La función SUM por defecto ya te da el monto total de el campo que le indicas por lo que no es necesario que uses ningún otro dato de la tabla, al parecer por lo que veo querías realizar una especia de suma haciendo iteraciones campo por campo pero esto es innecesario. Después de eso en tu código deberías de poner eso dentro de una variable y eso debería de ser todo.